# How to apply Calendar hours on a calendar using google API

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I plan on using google calendar as a means to schedule availability for a room.   For example  room A is available Monday-Friday 8am to 5pm so room A's calendar should only have free during those times.   In the google calendar API how do I block out the time where it is unavailable (ie. 5:01pm - 12am, 12am - 7:59am)?

Do I create an recurring event in the times where I want it blocked off?

I've also read about resource Calendars but I had trouble understanding how you can schedule availability for a resource.  For example how do I say a resource is available from 8am to 5pm? The api documentation only shows the resource information.

Links:
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/resources/calendars

https://developers.google.com/calendar/recurringevents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the API documentation, it enables you to query a calendar for the times at which it's considered busy (has events in it).
[Freebusy](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/freebusy)

How will your users interface with the event scheduling app? Assuming the requests are handled  on the server side - you are using the REST API so they probably are - you could query the API for the list of times that are busy and compare against the time slots requested by the user.

If the calendar is busy, you return the error in a callback function as the first parameter. If not, you execute the code for scheduling the event and return 'false' as the first parameter thereby indicating there's no error.